# how to prove $ B = ( \beta \Rightarrow \gamma) \Rightarrow (\alpha \Rightarrow \beta)\Rightarrow \alpha\Rightarrow \gamma $ using natural deduction

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, natural-deduction

I tried to follow a similar question solving another statement using natural deduction but it still seems hard to understand every time I get a different solution I can't figure out a methodology to solve these kinds of statements. Can you guys explain to me how to solve this with a methodology to follow for any other statement so I can be able to solve them my self?

This is the statement I'm trying to solve:

$$ B = ( \beta \Rightarrow \gamma)  \Rightarrow (\alpha \Rightarrow  \beta)\Rightarrow \alpha\Rightarrow \gamma. $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) $(β ⇒ \gamma)$ ---assumed [a]

2) $(α ⇒ β)$ --- assumed [b]

3) $\alpha$ --- assumed [c]

4) $\beta$ --- from 3) and 2) by ⇒-elimination

5) $\gamma$ --- from 4) and 1) by ⇒-elimination

6) $\alpha ⇒ \gamma$ --- from 3) and 5) by ⇒-introduction, discharging [c]

7) $(α ⇒ β) ⇒ (\alpha ⇒ \gamma)$ --- from 2) and 6) by ⇒-introduction, discharging [b]

> 8) $(β ⇒ \gamma) ⇒ ((α ⇒ β) ⇒ (\alpha ⇒ \gamma))$ --- from 1) and 7) by ⇒-introduction, discharging [a].

Comment: can you clarifies the methodologies you are using step by step please , thank you for your help

Comment: or refer me to a course who explain more this methodologies

Comment: @ZeRubeus - I'm assuming that you know the inference rules for *Natural Deduction* ... In this case, we need only two : $\rightarrow$-elimination (the "old" *modus ponens*) is : from $\varphi$ and $\varphi \rightarrow \psi$, infer $\psi$ ($\varphi, \varphi \rightarrow \psi \vdash \psi$) and $\rightarrow$-introduction ; from a derivation of $\psi$ from $\varphi$, infer $\varphi \rightarrow \psi$ ( if $\varphi \vdash \psi$, then $\vdash \varphi \rightarrow \psi$),

Comment: Basically, with this type of formula, start bottom-up : to derive $p \rightarrow (q \rightarrow r)$ we need to derive $ (q \rightarrow r)$ from assumption $p$, and so on ...

Comment: The way you write it makes very hard to track which assumption holds for which lines. Adding indentation as if in Fitch style system would help.